# Modifiying Sublime Text Syntax Highlighting for HTML Tags

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, color-scheme

I've tried numerous colour schemes for Sublime Text 2 and I've found a number that look great for javascript and php, but they also have terrible distinction between text and tags in HTML.

What I'm looking to do is make HTML tags the *same colour* as the beginning and end tag (`<>`). Right now the left and right chevrons appear the same colour as plain text, which can be dizzying to read.

[image: Bad syntax colouring in "Frontier"]
Colour scheme [`Frontier`](https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes)

Realizing it's not the colour scheme but the syntax definitions for HTML, I looked in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/HTML/HTML.tmLanguage` to make the modification.

Problem is, the XML file is littered with `&gt;` and `&lt;` and no documentation for the file itself other than the [unofficial documentation for syntax definitions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-2/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html?highlight=tmlanguage). Anyone know how I could merge the beginning and end tag definitions to be the same as the tags themselves?

The other option, of course, it to edit each theme I like and make sure the tags and the chrevrons are coloured the same, but I figured a global edit would make more sense in my case.

[image: Better syntax highlighting in "Phoenix Dark Blue"]
Colour scheme [`Phoenix Dark Blue`](https://github.com/netatoo/phoenix-theme)

For example, `Phoenix Dark Blue` solves this problem by using the following definition,

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Variable, String Link, Tag Name</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>variable, support.other.variable, string.other.link, entity.name.tag, entity.other.attribute-name, meta.tag, declaration.tag</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#787878</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of further `.tmLanguage`-related emergencies, take note of the [TextMate Manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/)'s [Language Grammars section](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars). Their examples are in [JSON](http://json.org/): a format infinitely more readable than PLIST but not a thing that Sublime Text can properly utilize. ST2 and ST3 users can use [PackageDev](https://github.com/SublimeText/PackageDev) to edit grammars in [YAML](http://yaml.org/).

As you've mentioned, and as confirmed by my regex search `&(g|l)t;`, there are *way too many* `<` or `>` tag delimiters within the Sublime Text 2 (build 2221) `HTML.tmLanguage` grammar file. Some HTML tags and wacky regex tag contexts are *so special* that they warrant a unique denotation, which unfortunately for us **includes re-specifying the scope and context of the tag delimiters, `<` and `>`,** rather than hooking in to some universal inequality symbol scope selector.

Luckily, *every*  instance of `&lt;` and `&gt;` is given a scope name of `punctuation.definition.tag.???.html`, where `???` could be `begin`, `end`, or nothing. Likewise, each HTML tag (`html` in `<html>`) is named quite a lot like `entity.name.tag.html`. Fortune be praised, it's time for regular expressions!

In your `HTML.tmLanguage` file – I'd actually suggest cloning a new one into `Packages/User` for safety's sake, although you'll have to rename the file and the grammar – perform a **regex** search for all offending scope names with:

```
punctuation\.definition\.tag.*(?=</string>)
```

…and replace every result (this should be as simple as one `Ctrl+V`) with the same name as the tags themselves, `entity.name.tag.html`. In my testing I also added another sub-scope past `tag` in case I needed to find the replacements later, so it looked like this:

```
entity.name.tag.delimiter.html
```

I've tested this with ST2's default color schemes, and it *should* work with other well-written themes.  Here it is with [Dayle Rees' Frontier](https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes):

[image: Frontier]

It even works in Sublime Text 3!

Answer (score 0):

ST2 is no longer supported (or running, as far as I know). Here is a quick ST3 solution.

To customize colors of 'tag' angle brackets, you must create a dict scope for tag activity, with foreground key and color string. Here is the correct syntax.

```
<dict>
<key>name</key>
<string>tag</string>
<key>scope</key>
<string>entity.name.tag, punctuation.definition.tag.begin, punctuation.definition.tag.end</string>
<key>settings</key>
<dict>
<key>foreground</key>
<string>#CCCCAA</string> <!-- custom tag color here -->
</dict>
</dict>
```

This scope is explained [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html).

More scopes to explore [here](https://gist.github.com/alehandrof/5361546).