# Sublime html tag theming

Tags: html, sublimetext

I've been trying to color code sublime and one problem I can't figure out is how to get the symbol " < " and " > " to be any other color other than white. Any help appreciated

ex of problem : [image]

Comment: Go to preferences, select the color scheme. You can find tons of varieties.

Comment: You could try the solution [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822408/modifiying-sublime-text-syntax-highlighting-for-html-tags).

Answer (score 0):

In your key bindings search for this binding:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+p"], "command": "show_scope_name" },
```

Move your cursor to be just **before** the needed character (syntax constant or whatever it's called), in your case the `<` character and press the binding. Look at your status bar, it will show the corresponding syntax path mine currently is:

```
text.html.basic meta.tag.script.html punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html
```

Then you need to edit your pen your theme file `something.tmTheme` and add the following definition:

```
    <dict>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>text.html.basic meta.tag.script.html punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#00FF00</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

That's it, now your `<` symbol is green as hell.

Repeat the same process for the `>` symbol. Do this to style/recolor any other defined syntax.

Please note, that scope path may be different for `.php` files and `.html` files, and it **IS** different for XML

Comment: I found { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+p"], "command": "show_scope_name" },
inside the binding, but I dont see anything for < or > nor do i see the syntax path. 

Sorry, I am really new to sublime. Is there an alternative explanation you can give me?

Comment: Ohhh I get it n.m. Should anyone else be wondering.

The binding ensures the combo of keys work. Then you go back to your actual document and for the tag you are interested in place the cursor in front and hit
ctrl+shit+alt+p and in the status (bottom left corner) you will get the path

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way of styling `<` and `>` - just use `punctuation.definition.tag` and you're all set. It works in HTML, XML, PHP, HTML5, etc., and since it covers both opening and closing tags you don't need to worry about changing two entries in your `.tmTheme` file should you decide to change the color.

Comment: That highly depends on what you want to achieve, as I see, the OP needs it for HTML tags and not PHP or other ones, so defining a concrete path will give more flexibility later on, if you decide to tweak things a bit more.